# how to use state in actions when we use useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am using hooks and context api.I have multiple actions that write them into seperate file.my problem this:in another file how can I access state?
I use this file for create my contexts:
createContext.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
  const Context = React.createContext();

  const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

    const boundActions = {};
    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
    }

    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };
  return { Context, Provider };
};
```

and when I want to create context I pass actions ,reducer and default values to createContext file and get Context and Provider from that.like this:
productContext.js

```
    import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";
    import {storeProducts, detailProduct} from "../data";

    const productReducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "GET_ITEM":
                return {...state, productDetail: action.productDetail};
           case "ADD_TOTALS":
            return {
                ...state,
                cartSubTotal: action.cartSubTotal,
                cartTotal: action.cartTotal,
                cartTax: action.cartTax
            };
   case "ADD_TO_CART":
            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.tempProducts,
                cart: [...state.cart, action.product]
            };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
    const getItem = (id) => {
        const product = **products**.find(item => item.id === id);
        return product;
    }

    const handleDetail = dispatch => (id) => {
        const productDetail = getItem(id);
        dispatch({type: "GET_ITEM", productDetail})
    };
const addToCart = dispatch => (id) => {
    let tempProducts = [...storeProducts];
    const index = tempProducts.indexOf(getItem(id));
    const product = tempProducts[index];
    product.inCart = true;
    product.count = 1;
    const price = product.price;
    product.total = price;
    dispatch({
        type: "ADD_TO_CART",
        tempProducts,
        product
    });
    const data = addTotals();
    dispatch({
        type: "ADD_TOTALS",
        cartSubTotal: data.cartSubTotal,
        cartTotal: data.cartTotal,
        cartTax: data.cartTax
    });
};
const addTotals = () => {
    let subTotal = 0;

    **cart**.map(item =>{ (subTotal += item.total)});

    const tempTax = subTotal * 0.1;
    const tax = parseFloat(tempTax.toFixed(2));
    const total = subTotal + tax;
    return {cartSubTotal: subTotal, cartTax: tax, cartTotal: total};
};
    export const {Provider, Context} = createDataContext(
        productReducer,
        {
            handleDetail,

        },
       {
        products: storeProducts,
        productDetail: detailProduct,
        cart: [],
        modalOpen: false,
        modalProduct: detailProduct,
        cartSubTotal: 0,
        cartTax: 0,
        cartTotal: 0
    );
```

I can not access cart and products that are bold.how can I use them?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing a lot of work in the action creator function that would make more sense as part of the reducer. For example, instead of this:

```
const productReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_ITEM':
      return { ...state, productDetail: action.productDetail };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const getItem = (id) => {
  // no access to state!
  const product = products.find((item) => item.id === id);
  return product;
};

const handleDetail = (dispatch) => (id) => {
  const productDetail = getItem(id);
  dispatch({ type: 'GET_ITEM', productDetail });
};
```

You can do this:

```
// action value
{ type: 'GET_ITEM', id: 1234 }

// reducer
const productReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_ITEM':
      const productDetail = state.products.find(
        (item) => item.id === action.id
      );
      return { ...state, productDetail };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Inside the reducer is where you have access to both the action and the state. Try to design your actions so that they contain the smallest amount of information possible to achieve your intention.